# How to make an AJAX call in Magnolia Blossom?

Tags: ajax, magnolia

I am new to Magnolia Blossom.

I have to perform an `AJAX` call in my application in Blossom. 
We have a Controller per component.  So I am unable to make an `AJAX` request.

Can anyone suggest how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

you may define a different Servlet (and web application context), you can define a servlet that handles all the requests that start for /rest/* and then below that on your web.xml you can define the blossom servlet.
All the rest is configuration, try to see how to create a webapp with 2 different contexts.

Answer (score 0):

The controllers you're using for rendering content are not accessible to requests coming in to the servlet container. Without content they're pretty useless and won't generate meaningful output. You need a separate DispatcherServlet handling these AJAX requests.

There's two ways to achieve this. You can either add a new DispatcherServlet to web.xml or you can add a servlet to your module that is installed when your module is installed.

The latter is the better choice because you won't need to have two separate ApplicationContexts. The one created in your module on startup will be the parent of both DispatcherServlets so both can access beans within it. You also won't need to update web.xml which makes module install easier and upgrades of Magnolia easier.

In your module descriptor add this snippet:

```
<servlets>
  <servlet>
    <name>dispatcher</name>
    <class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</class>
    <mappings>
      <mapping>/ajax/*</mapping>
    </mappings>
    <params>
      <param>
        <name>contextConfigLocation</name>
        <value>classpath:/ajax-servlet.xml</value>
      </param>
    </params>
  </servlet>
</servlets>
```

This, and other topics, is described in the Magnolia wiki https://wiki.magnolia-cms.com/display/WIKI/Adding+a+DispatcherServlet+to+a+Blossom+module

Comment: Hi @sigget, can make more clarify, because i am very new to blossom.
What is the module descriptor in blossom? 
Is it *module.xml file ?
If we add here then what is the next step to do?

Comment: If you have any sample example it would be more helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, the module descriptor is your src/main/resources/META-INF/magnolia/<module name>.xml file. After you've updated it you need to reinstall the module.

Comment: What will be the content of ajax-servlet.xml file. and after configuring in module descriptor how can we write the controller specific for AJAX call. If we can access a controller through ajax request then  we can write a simple spring controller. is it correct ?

Comment: ajax-servlet.xml will be a plain Spring bean definition xml file. Write controllers is plain normal Spring style.

Comment: I did that and  i have created an controller and just tried to call that method from browser using the method url but page not found error message is showing. Did i miss something ?

Comment: I have configured the ajax-servlet.xml in that I specified the base package of controller and while initialization process the controllers are not at all instatiated.

Comment: Do you see your DispatcherServlet in the configuration app here: /server/filters/servlets/dispatcher ?

Do you see this in your logs: Initializing filter [Wrapper for dispatcher servlet] ?

Note that you should not add the /ajax/ to path on request mapping methods. If you do your controller is reachable as /ajax/ajax/<something>

I have also improved the wiki page linked to in the answer, have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to get out, you can also use REST module of Magnolia. To e.g. read a title of website you can just call `http://localhost:8080/magnoliaAuthor/.rest/properties/v1/website/demo-project/siteTitle` more details at [documentation](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/REST+API)

And you can use REST module to also very easily add your own endpoints by just annotating source code.

HTH,
Jan