# Can we call a controller method directly by its url like Spring Controller in Magnolia?

Tags: spring-mvc, magnolia

I am doing an application using Magnolia blossom module.
We are having **Controller** per **Component** . When we make a request through Network call using URL we are using the page URL not the url we mention in the Controller.

e.g. 
 We have a page called **successPage** and its url is `/successPage`

in `SuccessPageComponent.java`

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/success", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String getSuccessPage(HttpServletRequest request) {
   ..........
   ..........
   return "redirect:successPage" ;
 }
```

When we are using an url `http://localhost:8080/myproject/successPage`,
the page is rendering.

When we are using an url `http://localhost:8080/myproject/success`

we are getting error page

> Oops, the page you have requested is not available.
>   Either its URL is incorrect or the page is not available on this channel, i.e. you are looking at it on a desktop browser, but the page is only served on the smartphone channel.

So some where [magnolia](https://www.magnolia-cms.com/) is taking care of executing the Controllers using respective `url` mapping.

- Hence I want to know what is the internal mechanism of magnolia that to execute a Controller method.
- How it is accessing the method how it is calling that?
- Can we write a controller of our own and execute it directly through `url` as we are doing in a simple `SPRING` application.

Please give a suggestion with explanation.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> Hence I want to know what is the internal mechanism of Magnolia that
>   to execute a Controller method.
>
> How it is accessing the method how it is calling that?

From [Magnolia Blossom Documentation](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Blossom+module):

Handler Mapping
Spring uses HandlerMappings to map a request to a handler (usually a controller). Blossom interrogates the HandlerMappings to find out how you have mapped your handlers. Your HandlerMapping needs to be a class inherited from AbstractUrlHandlerMapping. This is usually the case, both Spring 2.5+ annotated controllers and BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping inherit from AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.

> Can we write a controller of our own and execute it directly through
>   url as we are doing in a simple SPRING application.

In theory, you can just add Spring servlet to Magnolia's filter chain where other servlets are defined `config:/server/filters/servlets` and map uri of your controller to that servlet. Since servlets are evaluated before page rendering starts, servlet will be executed instead of page.
What I'm not sure about is why would you want to do that? Whole point of combining the two is to get power or declaration and execution of business logic of Spring together with possibility of letting editors enhance the visual content of the page. With direct execution, you are loosing the advantage of combining Magnolia and Spring together.

Comment: Hi @jan Actually I want to use AJAX implementation in my application and for that i am unable to do that. By adding the dispatcher servlet in module descriptor, its not working out.

Comment: What is not working? Did you reinstall the module after updating the descriptor? Change will not be picked up w/o reinstall. In another idea, if it really doesn't work or if all you want is ajax version of the content on the page you might want to create variation of the page that would return json array upon being called w/ e.g. .ajax extension - if you want to go down that road, you can look at https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Configuring+variations+in+a+page+template

Answer (score 0):

> Hence I want to know what is the internal mechanism of magnolia that
>   to execute a Controller method.

In your module class your instantiating a BlossomDispatcherServlet that manages the controllers used to render content. These controllers are not accessible from the outside because the servlet container has no knowledge of this servlet.

> How it is accessing the method how it is calling that?

When a request comes in it is handled by the Magnolia rendering engine which finds the content to be rendered and the template to use to render it. At this point the DispatcherServlet is called to invoke the controller. This happens by "faking" a forward or include request when the service() method is called on the servlet.

If you're interested in how this works in practice have a look at the source of BlossomTemplateRenderer and BlossomDispatcherServlet.

> Can we write a controller of our own and execute it directly through url > as we are doing in a simple SPRING application.

Yes, by adding a DispatcherServlet that manages controllers not used to render content. On [your other question about this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30123766/how-to-make-an-ajax-call-in-magnolia-blossom) I have posted an answer on how to do that. It is also in the [Blossom documentation](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Blossom+module#Blossommodule-AdditionalDispatcherServletsandAJAXcalls) as of today.